# Combining multiple row meta info from MYSQL database to one response

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm working with an existing database and I have a question I know you SQL guys can nail. I have 2 tables, on has an item id and a description, the other stores all the meta for said items.

my two tables are like this....

```
items- 
----------------
id | description
----------------

itemsmeta-
-----------------------------------------
itemmeta_id | item_id | fieldkey | value
-----------------------------------------
```

What I need to do is get a single response, hopefully as an object or array based on a given item ID. So i'd like to say get all meta info based on specific item id.

If I do something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN itemsmeta ON itemsmeta.item_id = items.id WHERE items.id = 1
```

it returns about 9 rows, one for each meta entry for item number one. Is it possible to structure my query to return one response?

Maybe something like:

Array( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [Name] => Blah Blah [Meta 1] => Blah Blah [Meta 2] => Blah Blah) ) and so on?

Comment: http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/ this might help

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GROUP_CONCAT** function

```
SELECT id, description, GROUP_CONCAT(value)
FROM items
LEFT JOIN itemsmeta  ON items.id = itemsmeta.item_id
GROUP BY item.id;
```